# Move off-screen SUB-window back to visible screen on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, off-screen

This is NOT a duplicate to the common question, how to get an application window from an offscreen position. I am familiar with those problems and know the solutions, like moving windows with SHIFT+WIN+ARROW keys, WIN+SPACE and Maximize, etc. However in my case I have a windows Qt-based application that has a child window that appears in some cases and this child window remembers it's position on 3rd monitor I don't have at home. No common tricks work to resolve this, since they cannot be applied to the child window; if they work at all, they get applied to the main window.

I could only find one similar case with Firefox sub-window and it had a solution specific for Firefox.

Any hints, please?

Comment: Do you know what sort of child window this is? It is a modal dialog, for instance? Can you see the window preview in the taskbar, right-click on that, and choose move?

Comment: @music2myear No, it's not a modal dialog, it's independent window, but it lacks properties of the main window. I create the window using a VB.NET module via API of the parent system (NX), thus having no influence on it's behavior, so I consider it irrelevant. It could be specific to q Qt framework, but I suspect it's specific to independent (sub) windows.

Comment: This is software you're writing yourself? This is a different question than it appears then, and really will likely get better answers at one of our programming sister sites.

Comment: @music2myear I'm sorry if I didn't express myself clearly. I am only writing a module, that opens a dialog built in the NX system, which is a Qt framework application. My question is thus either general for all Qt applications under windows or general to all windows applications (for sub-windows in this case). Obviously, I can't tell which one it is, but it has nothing to do with the software I'm writing, since the UI is handled by the master application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said, no trick worked. Even changing setup between mulitple screen modes.

However, I found that for this very reason the system has a reset button located at `Preferences --> User Interface: Layout`, which one has to trigger and restart the NX system. This is obviously not a general solution for qt sub-windows on Windows, let alone all the sub-windows on Win10. But at least it helped in my case.

[image]